# Order when calculating using partial integration

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

Is the order important when calculating partial integration? When I for example have an integral $$ \int e^x \sin(2x)$$ and the formula for partial integration is $$ \int u v' = u v- \int u' v$$ So when I solve this problem, is the $$e^x \Rightarrow u$$ or is $$sin(2x) \Rightarrow u$$

Comment: It works both ways.

Comment: In this situation, either works, both give the same answer, and both take the same number of steps.

Comment: In other cases one way might work, but the other not. It's not that one way is invalid, but that the integrals becomes more difficult.

Comment: Your question is almost equal to this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408634/752 .

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of integrals, there is absolutely no difference between the two approaches. You will get the same result. Try by yourself to be convinced

Answer (score 0):

The first function and second function, $u$ and $v$ respectively, are decides by ILATE rule. In $95\%$ it works.

I: Inverse, L:Logarithmic, A: Algebraic, T: Trigonometric and E: Exponential.

We can take Exponential function as the %2nd% function as it is easy to integrate.

In your case, both ways will give the correct answer in equal no of steps.